# How to count two words as 1 in same line

Tags: javascript, regex

In the text file I've got, each sentence is represented with a specific type such as: contrast.

A contrasting sentence can either be represented with a tag "CONTRAST" or "CONTR" or "WEAKCONTR". For instance:

> IMPSENT_CONTRAST_VIS(Studying networks in this way can help to
>   identify the people from whom an individual learns , where
>   conflicts_MD:+ in understanding_MD:+ may originate , and which
>   contextual factors influence learning .)

So I count these with following expression: `/(\_(WEAK))|(\_CONTRAST)|(\_CONTR(\_|\())/g` which works perfectly fine.

Now the problem is some sentences are expressed with more than one contrast tag such as CONTR & WEAKCONTR together. For instance:

> IMPSENT_CONTRAST_EMPH_WEAKCONTR_VIS(Studying_MD:+ networks in this way
>   can help to    identify_MD:+ the people from whom an individual learns
>   , where    conflicts_MD:+ in understanding_MD:+ may originate , and
>   which    contextual factors influence learning .)

At this point I have to count these as 1 not 2. Do you have any idea how possible this is with RegExp?

Comment: are the tags always at the start of the line and followed by a paren?

Comment: Why do you need the exact number of "CONTR" tags? Isn't simply knowing that one such tag is present enough? Just curious...

Comment: @Mathletics tags can be either followed by parenthesis or underline and tags always start with underline such as _CONTR( or _CONTR_

Comment: @wroniasty I think the point is NOT to return the exact number, but rather to find any line with tags, and only note each line once.

Comment: @wroniasty What I actually want to know is how many sentences are mentioning a contrasting idea. These are represented with the 3 tags I wrote up there however sometimes same sentence contains 2 tags for contrast which causes me to count that 1 sentence as 2. Hope it is clear.

Comment: Is processing one line/sentence at a time an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookaheads to assert it, and then count the matches:

```
(?=\w*_(?:WEAK|CONTRAST|CONTR[_)]))\b\w+\b
```

Demo here: http://regex101.com/r/xP2yI7/3
Notice the match count.

This will match the whole `IMPSENT_CONTRAST_EMPH_WEAKCONTR_VIS` expression, but only if it matches the part in the lookahead, which filters for the keywords you're looking after. This will match even if you have multiple such sentences on the same line.

Also, I've simplified your regex a bit, retaining the same meaning. Notice you don't have to escape the `_`.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot really. I can't give you an up as it requires 15 reputation, sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

You really just care if the tag shows up in the line at all, so just grab the whole line, provided it has a tag, like so:

```
/^([A-Z_]+(WEAK|CONTRAST|CONTR)+[A-Z_]*)/gm
```

> From the start of the line **^** look for a word block with **A-Z** or **_** followed by the tag, optionally followed by more words/underscores.

[DEMO](http://refiddle.co/18z1)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding `\w+`:

```
/(\_(WEAK\w+))|(\_CONTRAST\w+)|(\_CONTR(\_\w+|\())/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
(^(\_(WEAK))|(\_CONTRAST)|(\_CONTR(\_|\()))
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain the code. If you do explain it (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes—and the questioner actually learns something!